# Django error when entering from multiple domains

Tags: django, django-admin, django-views

I'm by setting two domains that point to the same IP of Django, but I can just logging in to one, on the other just will not let me, from the admin or web always redirects me to the logging box, tried everything but nothing.

In test environment I have django running on runserer and the / etc / hosts as follows:

```
# This if it works
127.0.0.1 talleres.host1.com
# This one does not work
127.0.0.1 talleres.host2.com
```

I think the problem is with django but not to start looking, anyone know about this?

Comment: Do you have ALLOWED_HOSTS set to allow both domains? .host1.com and .host2.com?

Comment: and try to add it but nothing (ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['talleres.host1.com','talleres.host2.com']) I forgot to mention, I can not go into the admin and login of the front

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your ALLOWED_HOSTS looks like this:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.host1.com',
                 '.host2.com',]
```

Comment: no, did not work, will not let me enter: [02/Oct/2013 14:05:50] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[02/Oct/2013 14:05:50] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1913

Comment: Is it just the admin, or can you not access anything?

Edit: Can you post some code,or errors? Would make it easier to debug.

Comment: is only login, try to debug using the method that i comment above, because apache does not say anything in the log, try to see for terminal "runserver" and modifying the host, but only says POST and then a GET returns the page login.